# UI Mapkit lag when addAnnotation called

Tags: swift, multithreading, mapkit, mkannotation, dispatch

I don't understand why the UI is not responding during 1 or 2 second (the time to get data from database) and this happen every 5 seconds even if I use `DispatchQueue`. I use `UIMapKit` for the map and Firebase to get data.

So, in the `viewDidLoad()` of my application I created a timer to execute the function sendMyLocation() every 5 seconds.

```
timerLocationRequest = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(mapVC.sendMyLocation), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

The function `sendMylocation()` call the function `addAnnotations(userArray: [User])`. I use `dispatch_queue` to launch this in background.

```
func sendMyLocation()
{
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.addAnnotations(userArray: self.userArray)
    }
}
```

The function addAnnotations add annotation from the userArray.

```
func addAnnotations(userArray: [User]) {
        self.findNearbyUsers() // This function fill the userArray

        // Here I create the annotations and at the end I add a tables of annotations to the mapView
        for onePeople in userArray {
            let oneUserPin = customPointAnnotation()
            oneUserPin.coordinate.latitude = onePeople.latitude
            oneUserPin.coordinate.longitude = onePeople.longitude
            oneUserPin.imageName = onePeople.photo
            oneUserPin.title = "\(onePeople.username)"
            self.userPinArray.append(oneUserPin)
        }
    DispatchQueue.main.async { 
        self.myMap.addAnnotations(self.userPinArray) // I add annotations array to the mapView
    }
}
```

To finish, the function `findNearbyUser()` get data from Firebase database (location and also details of users near from me).

```
 func findNearbyUsers() {
    if let myLocation = self.manager.location {

        let theGeoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: self.databaseRef.child("positions"))
        let circleQuery = theGeoFire!.query(at: myLocation, withRadius: 0.3) //300 meters
        var i=0

          // Here I get keys of people near from me
        _ = circleQuery!.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key, location) in

            if !self.nearbyUsers.contains(key!) && key != self.meUser.user_position_id {
                self.nearbyUsers.append(key!)
                let oneUser = User()
                oneUser.user_id = key!
                oneUser.latitude = (location?.coordinate.latitude)!
                oneUser.longitude = (location?.coordinate.longitude)!
                self.userArray.insert(oneUser, at: i)
                i+=1
            }
        })

        // Here I take details from users near from me
    circleQuery?.observeReady({
        for user in self.userArray {
            self.databaseRef.child("users/\(user.user_id)").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
                let value = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
                user.user_id = value["id_user"] as! String
                user.photo = value["photoURL"] as! String
                user.username = value["username"] as! String
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The problem come from the adding of annotations on the `mapView` because when I comment this line in the function `addAnnotations(userArray: [User])`, the UI doesn't stop to respond every 5 seconds.
`self.myMap.addAnnotations(self.userPinArray)`

Do you have any solution or is there something I did wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried putting a completion handler on `findNearbyUsers` and use that to then call your `addAnnotations` function?

Comment: I tested but that changed nothing... Thanks anyway !